# Do I need a recirculating pump on the Bradford White hot water heater in combination with my Rinnai tankless that has its own recirculating pump

Tags: plumbing, water

I have a Rinnai tankless AND a recirculating pump AND a small Bradford White hot water (combination). Do you need a recirculating pump on the Bradford?

Comment: How are they connected

Answer (score 2):

A recirculation pump is usually used to ensure that you have "instant" hot water at the taps furthest from the hot water heater, so this is something only *you* can determine.

If you get hot water "fast enough" at your furthest taps, then no, you don't need the pump. If you have to "wait forever" (whether forever is 5 seconds or 2 minutes - it's up to you), then sure, the recirculation pump can be very helpful by returning tepid water sitting in the pipes back to (one of) the water heaters so that you've always got hot water at (or very close to) the tap ready to go.

The advantage is that you're not wasting<sup>*</sup> time & water by running it down the drain, but the drawback is that your pump is running 24/7 (though some have a timer and can be set to only run at the times you're *most likely* to use water - you still have to wait at other times), and you're burning electricity to save time.

<sup>*</sup>You're not really "wasting" the water, it's not like it's being poofed into nothingness. It just goes to the wastewater plant, gets treated with the rest of the waste water and returned to a river somewhere so it can evaporate, become a cloud and rain down again. You *are* having to pay for the privilege though.

Comment: Thank you.  I had to unplug the pump anyway since it was tripping the circuit breaker.  I still have plenty of hot water and nothing is very far away so it only takes less than a minute to get the hot water.  I appreciate your through answer.

Comment: You may want to look into _why_ it was tripping the breaker. If it's a bad pump, you should probably remove it from the plumbing system and toss it so others aren't trying to plug it in and getting shocked. If there are other issues, it's possible that something else will cause the trip and someone could still get hurt.

Comment: Also, please take the [tour] to learn the proper way(s) of saying "thanks", as "thank you" comments and (especially) answers are frowned upon.